# How to do a foreach within INSERT?

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, insert

When I enter data to mysql it shows as below image, I want to take all the data to a one row, not in many rows as below image. but since I'm entering data using an array I only have access to one element at once. So how can I enter data to a single line? below is a snip of my code and a snip from my table ,  thank you very much.

```
$array = array("AAPL","GOOG","YHOO","FB","MSFT","NKE","SBUX");

foreach ($array as $s) {
    $sss="PR".$s
    $amount=//some value from $_POST
    $value=//some value from $_POST

    $sql = "INSERT INTO portfolio ({$s} , {$sss}) VALUES ('{$amount}', '{$value}')";
}
```

Snip from MYSQL table
[image]

Comment: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: You have to create a dynamic statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first add those "PR.." columns to your array and then use implode() to build your into-clause.

```
$array = array("AAPL","GOOG","YHOO","FB","MSFT","NKE","SBUX");
$amount = 'dunno';
$value = 'something';
foreach ($array as $s) {
    $array[] = "PR" . $s;
}
$sql = 'INSERT INTO portfolio (' . implode(',', $array) . ') 
            VALUES ("' .$amount . '", "' . $value . '")';
echo $sql; // INSERT INTO portfolio (AAPL,GOOG,YHOO,FB,MSFT,NKE,SBUX,PRAAPL,PRGOOG,PRYHOO,PRFB,PRMSFT,PRNKE,PRSBUX) VALUES ("dunno", "something")
exit;
```

Can't build the coomplete query though because you didn't specify what kind of data $amount and $value are.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("AAPL","GOOG","YHOO","FB","MSFT","NKE","SBUX");
$keys = array();
$values = array();
foreach ($array as $s) {
$sss="PR".$s;
$amount=//some value from $_POST
$value=//some value from $_POST
$keys[] = "`{$sss}`";
$keys[] = "`{$s}`";
$values[] = "'{$value}'";
$values[] = "'{$amount}'";
}
$query = "INSERT INTO 'portfolio' (" . implode(",", $keys) . ")     VALUES (" . implode(",", $values. ");";
```

Comment: Please add explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just put insert statement out side the for loop

```
   $array = array("AAPL","GOOG","YHOO","FB","MSFT","NKE","SBUX");
    $sss='';$amount='';$value='';
    foreach ($array as $s) {
        $sss.=$s.",PR".$s.',';
        $amount.= "'VALUE for WITHOUT PR','VALUE for WITH PR',";
        $value.="'VALUE for WITHOUT PR','VALUE for WITH PR',";//some value from $_POST
    }
    $sss = rtrim($sss,',');
    $amount = rtrim($amount,',');
    $value = rtrim($value,',');
    echo $sql = "INSERT INTO portfolio ( {$sss}) VALUES ({$amount}, {$value})";
```